# Dynamically build routes using react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm building an application that will call out to an API prior to bootstrapping React. This API will tell me which features I need to load based on the user's subscription.

The API will return an array of objects with the pattern outlined below

```
links: [
    {
        label: 'Payment Reconciliation',
        component: './components/_paymentReconciliation/paymentReconciliationPage',
        url: '/paymentreconciliation'
    },
    {
        label: 'Device Integration',
        component: './components/_deviceIntegration/deviceIntegrationPage',
        url: '/deviceintegration'
    }
]
```

It's easy enough to map the links to produce dynamic `Routes`

```
export default function Routes() {
    let featureRoutes = config.FEATURES.links.map((menuItem, i) => {
        return (
            <Route path={menuItem.url} component={require(menuItem.component).default} key={i} />
        )
    });
    return (<div>
        <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage} />
        {featureRoutes}
    </div>
    )
}
```

This obviously isn't working. I'm struggling figuring out how to not need an import statement for every possible Component that might be loaded. Also should the API be returning the path to the component or just the component name? I've seen examples using something like `handler={require(PathToComponent)}` That hasn't proven to work either.

Any help here would be appreciated

Comment: I thing your featureRoutes  will be an array.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES imports must be [statically analyzable](http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html#ecmascript-6-modules), so you can't dynamically require them. Instead, you can use a CommonJS style import to dynamically require files:

```
var myFile = require('myFile');
```

Combine that with the [route-config approach](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/route-config), and you're all set.

You can see an example of this in the documentation module of this Pluralsight course: [Creating Reusable React Components](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/react-creating-reusable-components/table-of-contents)

Answer (score 2):

Try requiring your path to the components to get a reference to that component.

```
export default function Routes() {
    let featureRoutes = config.FEATURES.links.map((menuItem, i) => {
        return (
            <Route path={menuItem.url} component={require(menuItem.component).default} key={i} />
        )
    });
    return (<div>
        <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage} />
        {featureRoutes}
    </div>
    )
}
```

Depending on how react-router implemented their component function this code might be a little off.  You can always render a react component using require with `React.createElement(require('./Component').default)`

Comment: I've tried this and get a `Error: Cannot find module "."`

Comment: Are you using webpack and if socan you post your config? can you post the generated paths in your link array?

Comment: I'm using create-react-app, so I didn't configure it myself... I'm shifting from Angular/Gulp so all pretty new to me

Comment: hmm i just tried tried it on my codebase and it worked.  Can you paste a few values of your links array while i check out the create-react-app bundle?

Comment: I edited question to have real examples of links array and what I've tried with your suggestion. routes.js is in root folder, components folder is top level

Comment: Are these relative paths from the component where the `require` functions are called? like is Routes in a folder that also has a components folder?

Comment: here is an image of where things are located https://imagebin.ca/v/3PrwN3dkqoBG. The paths work when I hard code the `<Route />` element

Comment: Maybe try @cory's answer with the route config